# mysql query using php doesnt retrieve all the rows in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a row into a database. I have inserted a few rows into a table. When I open the database on phpmyadmin it seems that all the rows were inserted. However when i then later try to retrieve a column from the table it only says that there is one row (the first inserted row). but it doesn't retrieve the other rows. Any help would be appreciated. 
below is the relevant code

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, 'select AssetId FROM About');
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
$len = count($rows);
print_r($rows);
$curAsId = $rows[$len - 1];
```

This is the output of print_r

> Array ( [0] => 1 )

when it should display many more rows

Comment: Hint: `mysqli_fetch_array()` only returns one row. Try `echo $result->num_rows` for an actual count

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, 'select AssetId FROM About');
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
$len = count($rows);
print_r($rows);
echo $curAsId = $rows[$len - 1];
}
```